# how to set the position of the camera with respect to an object of the scene?

Tags: camera, origin

I'm new with blender. I want to set cameras at different positions in the scene with respect to an origin point. I don't know how to do the steps I think I should follow:

1. Set the origin at the point of interest taking into account that I want to position it at Z = 0 m, and on the line between a building and the floor (see the attached figure). I don't know how to exactly set this origin considering the restriction of the building and the floor. Buildings were imported from OSM.
2. Set camera position with respect to the new origin.

I hope you can help me.
Many thanks!

[image]

After the first answers I received, I tried the example offered by Chris and it did work but I still have doubts about how to position the camera. I show you the example of the monkey. Here I would like to position the camera at a distance of 10 m from the monkey at the beginning. Why is it not aligned with the x axis if the location is set (10, 0, 0)?
Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: The world origin cannot move, but you can parent the cameras to an Empty and then move the empty about as needed.

Comment: Consider loading the Add Camera Rigs addon, and use the Dolly Camera Rig. It's already set up with a target empty at its front that it tracks, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel by building something similar from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

1. add an empty
2. parent the empty to the camera
3. now you can set keyframes on z-rotation for the empty on frame 0 (0) and frame 100 (360)
4. add location keyframe for the empty on frame 100
5. move your empty to your second point of interest
6. keyframe new position of empty at frame 150
7. now you can set keyframes on z-rotation for the empty on frame 151 (0) and frame 250 (360)
8. you can repeat step 5-7 for several points of interests, but of course you have to adapt the frames!

if you prefer to watch tutorial videos (which i do too because it is much to follow), check this out:
https://youtu.be/_RqDQuLfV1E

UPDATE:

1. to set the camera to a position just change x,y,z coordinate you want
2. add "track to constraint" -> choose target your cube/building/whatever
3. repeat steps from above to rotate the camera around the building

you can also check my tutorial for this:

https://youtu.be/B4jk75gbQwo

UPDATE & hint:

if you do not see all tabs, just hover with the mouse over it and scroll up/down to see more.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! I tried your example, Chris, and I could follow it! I still have doubts about how to set the first position of the camera: I need to test different distances of the camera from the empty. How could I locate it with respect to it? I do not feel confortable with the camera object yet. Many thanks again for your help!

Comment: of course you can keyframe the distance as well. Just choose "local" as transformation orientation. Then select camera -> tap G -> Z -> move cursor and control the distance you want and you can keyframe the location camera.

Comment: Hi Chris,I was not able to position it where I wanted... I don't know how to set the location introducing the exact values I want (not using the cursor). Is there any video you could recommend me?

Comment: i updated my answer and made a new tutorial. Just be patient - my internet is not that fast...it might take some time to upload. :(

Comment: Thank you Chris. I tried to do it but I was not successful. I don't see the vertical tab about the constraints and it is difficult for me to set the target then. I think I don't have the basic knowledge to do what I wanted to do... How do I set more vertical tabs (e.g. constraints) in the Properties editor? Do I have to use any script?  Thank you and sorry for taking your time.

Comment: if you do not see all tabs, just hover with the mouse over it and scroll up/down to see more.
 -> updated my answer